# Target parent product on bestseller query if best selling product is a child

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-collection, best-seller

How would I get the top 10 bestsellers like targeting the parent if the best seller is a child product.

I use the following code to get the bestsellers

```
 public function getBestsellerCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()->setModel(
            'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product'
        );

        $collection->getSelect()->limit(10);

        return $collection;
    }
```

but if the targeted product is a child product this would break with the following sql error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 10) AS `t`' at line 1, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (LIMIT 10) AS `t`
```